# ¿Cómo puedo agregar variables a mi cuerpo (Body) de email, si este es escrito en HTML y mi script en Python?

Tags: html, python, variables, email

Quiero enviar un correo con Python, el cuerpo del correo es una plantilla en HTML, sin embargo quiero que el usuario ingrese ciertos datos que se modifiquen en el cuerpo del correo al momento de enviarlo

```
self.body = """Cordial saludo: <br/> <br/>
                       Se adjunta informe de recepcion de la planilla **self.ent5.get()**  con placa  **self.ent6.get()** recepcionado de la ciudad de  **self.ent3.get()** el cual presenta:
"""
```

Comment: Bienvenido.  Por favor, aclara qué quieres hacer e incluye el código para que te podamos ayudar mejor. Gracias.

Comment: Hola Angel, gracias, quiero enviar un correo con Python, el cuerpo del correo es una plantilla en HTML, sin embargo quiero que el usuario ingrese ciertos datos que se modifiquen en el cuerpo del correo al momento de enviarlo.

Comment: Echa un vistazo a https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/python/capitulo-14/envio-de-e-mail-desde-python

Comment: Bueno suponiendo que todo el backend esta en python, solo captura los valores provenientes y agregalos al mensaje